# Graph of a measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, integration

I am reading through Terence Tao, and I was wondering how one would prove that if $f:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ is measurable, then the area under $f$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^{d + 1}$.

Comment: Do you mean that the set $\{(x,f(x)):x\in\mathbb{R}^d\}$ is measurable in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$?

Comment: or are you thinking of $\{(x,y)| y <= f(x)\}$?

Comment: The area under $f$ sounds like $\int f d \mu$.

Comment: the second one.

Comment: ${(x,y)|y<=f(x)}$

Answer (score 1):

Approximate $f$ from below by an increasing sequence of simple functions. The area under $f$ is the countable union of the areas under these simple functions, so we've reduced to the case that $f$ is simple.

It's easy to further reduce to the case that $f$ is the characteristic function of a measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^d$.  So WLOG $f = \chi_E$.

Maybe you've already proved that $E \times [0,1)$ is measurable?  If not, try taking intersecting $E$ against the unit cubes to reduce to the case that $E$ is bounded. Then you can directly approximate $E$ by open sets and that will lead to an approximation of $E \times [0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is I would prove it for piecewise constant mesurable functions (it's trivial) and then use that every mesurable function is the limit of an incresing sequence of such functions... What do you think?